# handling successful form submission with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In my application I'm using a plugin that generates the following markup:

```
<form id="addCommentForm" 
  action="/foo/add" 
  method="post" 
  onsubmit="
    jQuery.ajax({type:'POST', data:jQuery(this).serialize(), 
      url:'/foo/add',

      success:function(data,textStatus) {
        jQuery('#comments').html(data);
      },           
    });
    return false">

<!-- form elements here -->
</form>
```

When the form is submitted successfully I want to do something else after the success handler defined by the plugin, say `alert('hello');`.

The reason I'm struggling with this is because I can't just add my code to the end of the success handler above, because this code is not under my control.

I looked for a form event that executes after `onsubmit` that I could attach my code to, but didn't find anything.

Comment: whole series of global ajax methods apart from ajaxSuccess  http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/

Answer (score 3):

If you can't really change it, you could use [.ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) to handle all the external ajax calls and filter the one you need:

```
$('form').ajaxSuccess(function(evt, request, settings) {
 if (settings.url == 'xxx')
     alert('test');
});
```

Not pretty but it might work for you.